# Why are there so many ways to do the same thing in programming? Here's an AJAX example:

Tags: ajax

Here is the way I have been taught to write AJAX requests (which is backwards compatible):

```
var request;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

request.open('GET', 'data.txt', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (request.readyState===4 && request.status===200) {   // If the request was successful
        console.log(request);                               // and has finished
        document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }
}

request.send();
```

And here is what I see other people doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'gamble.php',
                    success: function() {
                        do stuff
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Why are there so many ways to code the same thing? It's so hard to learn programming for me because of this, whenever I ask a question they write the code completely different to how I have been told to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do things in programming because people have different preferences and some things are optimized for one situation more than another.

In the example you give, your first block is written entirely in plain JavaScript; the second requires the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com). The former is likely to grant better performance in most situations because it doesn't require you to load a library over the Internet in addition to the network call you're already making. However, it may be easier to do it using jQuery if you're already using jQuery in the rest of your project.

In other words, there's no use in loading an entire library to make one network call.

Because there are so many different situations, conditions, and restraints in programming, there are many solutions to one problem, and I think that that's something to be thankful for rather than to dread.

Answer (score 2):

One is using the jQuery library the other is raw JavaScript.

jQuery is JavaScript to make it easier (in theory and in practice).

But just chose you poison and go with that. There are no perfect solutions in most programming situations.

Comment: Is the jQuery version backwards compatible?

Comment: JQuery is written in Javascript - so yes.